# How to execute php files with php56 and Nginx for OSX?

Tags: php, macos, nginx

I am trying to execute php files with php56 and Nginx those are installed by brew.

`brew install nginx
brew install php56`

So, `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is here.

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        server_name  localhost;
        listen       8080;
        root   /Users/kent/work;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
    include servers/*;
}
```

I make a directory `/Users/kent/work/html` with a html file `index.html`.

```
<h1>this is my first file!</h1>
```

It works in `http://localhost:8080/html/index.html`.

And I make a directory `/Users/kent/work/php` with a php file `index.php`.

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

It has not browsed in `http://localhost:8080/php/index.php`.
Strangely it makes downloading index.php file.

I should browse php info in browser.
Am I doing anything wrong? Would you give some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you did not include fpm support in your php brew install

```sh
$ brew install php56 --with-fpm --without-apache
```

Validate that you have php and php-fpm installed

```sh
$ php -v
$ php-fpm -v
```

**Alternative**

Although not related to your original question, OSX comes with apache. That could be an alternative.

Also if you are using Laravel (or a number of other frameworks are supported out the box) you could also look at [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/valet) which is a nice development alternative using the Caddy server.

**Update: Additional information**

Check that php-fpm has actually started and listening on port 9000. As per my comment you can check that using:

```
$ lsof -Pni4 | grep LISTEN | grep php
```

You should see something like

```
php-fpm   50622 YourUsername    6u  IPv4 0xe686e4bdbc1e41b3      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   50636 YourUsername    0u  IPv4 0xe686e4bdbc1e41b3      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
```

You can manually start the service, using

```
$ brew services start homebrew/php/php56
```

You would also have needed to register the launcher on startup, using

```
$ mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
$ cp /usr/local/opt/php56/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
$ launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist
```

If you do not see an php-fpm entry from `lsof` check the following for clues

- The contents of `/var/log/syslog.log` for something containing the string `homebrew.mxcl.php56`
- Check `/usr/local/var/log/php-fpm.log` and make sure it is owned by the correct user and the user has access to that directory.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your support! however if I command php-fpm -v, `my console returns PHP 5.6.23 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Jul 24 2016 11:25:06) (DEBUG) Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies`. So php-fpm has been installed but something wrong.

Comment: @KentFujii Has php-fpm started and is it listening on port 9000, you can check that using `$ lsof -Pni4 | grep LISTEN | grep php`